# Растянуть пустой div на 100% без использования js

Tags: html, css

Добрый день.

Сразу к вопросу, есть такой Html:

```
 <td width="120" rowspan="3" nowrap>
 <div class="rlower">

 </div>
 </td>
```

(это боковой блок сайта)

rlower - имеет такой css:

```
 display: table-cell; //это я нагуглил на отечественном форуме но не помогло
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 min-height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
 border: solid 2px red;
 float: left;
```

Гуглить я пробовал на отечественных форумах - как всегда, людей с подобным вопросом посылают куда по дальше, хотя вопрос в принципе простой, на мой взгляд.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, дать позишн релатив ячейке, а контейнеру в нем абсолют, и он уже послушно будет закрывать всю ячейку и по ширине, и по высоте. Важно не забыть про паддинги, марджины и все такое, что может давать "щели".

```
<td width="120" height="150">
  <div class="rlower">

  </div>
</td>

td{
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
}
td div.rlower{
  position: absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  margin: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;

}
```

Comment: а если укоротить ваш вариант, то он не будет также работать? :) или он тогда превращается в мой?

`td{
  padding: 0px;
}
td div.rlower{
  margin: 0px;
  height:100%;
}`

Comment: незнаю, честное слово. надо попробовать. ...но обычно делаю так. так как сказал, так как результат предсказуем и я знаю как это работает.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что по ширине особых проблем растянуть блок нет, а вот чтобы растянуть блок по высоте на 100%, нужно, чтобы родительский блок имел высоту и эта высота была больше 0.

Если рассматривать ваш пример, то можно написать так:

```
<td width="120" height="150">
  <div class="rlower">

  </div>
</td>
```

И не нужно никаких `display: table-cell`, просто `height:100%`, а вот `width:100%` для `<div>` не надо, так как по ширине он по умолчанию растягивается на 100% родителя.